# Javascript Client-Side Beverage Price Calculator

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a personal project where I'd like to take user input via a form's text boxes, perform a calculation on it, and display the result on the same page. I work in a restaurant and would like to simplify the process of calculating the cost of a cocktail. I'm new to Javascript and this is my first proper project. I'm having difficulty figuring out what to do after storing the user input into a variable. I have created an object "drinkPrices" with the three different categories of drink types under the "name" keyword, the respective prices under the other keywords, and then a method that calculates the prices. I'm unsure if this approach is correct and ANY feedback/suggestions/help would be much appreciated.

Main difficulties: 
 1. Am I storing the user input correctly?
 2. How do I take the user input and reference it to the method in the object I have created? 
 3. How do I display the results of the calculation on the page?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="submitAlert.js"></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="theform">
    Enter Spirit Name:<br>
    <input type="text" id="sname" name="spiritname"><br>
    Enter Spirit Amount (in ounces):<br>
    <input type="text" id="samount" name="spiritamount">
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="return foo();" />
</form>
</body>
<p id="outputarea"> ...Output area is right here...</p>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
var drinkPrices =  {
    name: ['rail', 'call', 'premium'],
    railPrice:  4,
    callPrice: 6,
    premiumPrice: 8,
    quantity: 0,
    calculatePrice: function() {
        if (name === 'rail') {
            calculatePrice = quantity * railPrice;
        } else if (name === 'call') {
            calculatePrice = quantity * callPrice;
        } else if (name ==='premium') {
            calculatePrice = quantity * premiumPrice;
        }
        return this.calculatePrice;
    }
```

}
//this is the code I have for when the user hits submit. I am missing a lot//

```
function foo() {
    var a = document.getElementById("sname").value;
    var b = document.getElementById("samount").value;

    alert("Submit button clicked!");
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some improvements for your further coding:
Replace `input` elements with `select` lists when you dealing with a predefined list of options, in this way you prevent accedential typos by the user.
When you use select and you're only interessted in corresponding values, use the `value` attribute on `option` tags.
When you need numerical inputs, use `<input type="number">` or `<input type="range" min="0" max="100" step="1">` (min/max/step are optional and can be added to number-inputs too).
Use the `onsubmit` on forms instead of `onclick` on buttons to let the browser validate the inputs (part of better practice).

Here I've hacked together an example:

```js
document.querySelector('#theform').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let price = this.spirit.value * 1;
  let amount = this.spiritamount.value * 1;
  let total = (price * amount).toFixed(2);
  document.querySelector('#outputarea').textContent = total;
});
```

```html
<form id="theform">
 Enter Spirit Name:<br>
 <select name="spirit">
  <option value="4">rail</option>
  <option value="6">call</option>
  <option value="8">premium</option>
 </select><br>
 Enter Spirit Amount (in ounces):<br>
 <input type="number" name="spiritamount" value="1">
 <br><br>
 <button>Calculate</button>
</form>
<p id="outputarea">0.00</p>
```

Here is another example with listed entries:

```js
let receipt = {};
const prices = {
  'rail': 4,
  'call': 6,
  'premium': 8
};

// clear the receipt
document.querySelector('#reset').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    receipt = {};
    document.querySelector('#outputarea').innerHTML = '';
});

document.querySelector('#theform').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let spirit = this.spirit.value;
  let amount = this.spiritamount.value * 1;
  if(spirit in receipt) {
    receipt[spirit] += amount;
  } else {
    receipt[spirit] = amount;
  }
  let list = '';
  let total = 0;
  for(const e in receipt) {
    let sum = prices[e] * receipt[e];
    list += `<div>${e} x ${receipt[e]} = ${sum.toFixed(2)}</div>`;
    total += sum;
  }
  list += `<hr>${total.toFixed(2)} ¤`;
  document.querySelector('#outputarea').innerHTML = list;
})
```

```html
<form id="theform">
 Select Spirit: <select name="spirit">
  <option>rail</option>
  <option>call</option>
  <option>premium</option>
 </select><br>
 Enter Spirit Amount (in ounces): <input type="number" name="spiritamount" value="1"><br><br>
 <button>Add to receipt</button> or <button id="reset">Reset</button>
</form>
<p id="outputarea"></p>
```

Comment: Thank you, Steven! What would I do if I wanted to enter the amount as a decimal? For example, 1.50 ounces.

Comment: You can specify the "step" attribute of number- and range-inputs in any precision you like (e.g. step="0.01" or step="0.5").

Comment: I see, thank you. Can you explain to me how you're using the receipt variable and the if statement, please? I'm having trouble figuring it out exactly.

Comment: Of course: when the selected spirit exist in receipt, increase the corresponding value by amount (don't override the value) otherwise set the property and value to an initial state (create it in the object).

Comment: you can refactor it to this, if you like: `if(!(spirit in receipt)) { receipt[spirit] = 0; } receipt[spirit] += amount;`
Then, the if-statement make sure that the entry exsist before you add values to it (without the if, the browser calculates `undefined + amount`, sounds scarry and is not a best practice).

Comment: I've been slowly looking over this over the last few days (it's been a great learning experience, thank you!) and have a few more questions. It'll be easier for me to understand once I figure out how to use the debugger on Web Storm. But in regard to "receipt", you created an empty object and then add the property "spirit" to it and increase "spirit" by "amount" correct? Should it be written as receipt['spirit'], or are the quotes not necessary? Would you also be able to explain what happens in the "for" loop? Also could you explain why you use the back-tick marks, please? Thank you very much!

Comment: 1. correct: `receipt={};` initializes an empty object, but i assign the current value of `spirit` as a property-key to receipt, which i increase by the value of `amount`. 2. When you write `receipt['spirit']` you just access `receipt.spirit`, that's a different property. 3. In the for-loop i sum together the total price and "print" the individual entities to the list (I add the string). 4. back-tick strings is a new feature from es2015/es6 called `Template literals` and makes string building easier: https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings (don't forget ▲)

Answer (score 1):

Just use a name-price map:

```
 const price = {
    rail:2,
    call:4,
    premium:6
 };
```

Then you can simply get the price:

```
 function calculatePrice() {
   const name = document.getElementById("sname").value;
   const amount = document.getElementById("samount").value;

   alert(`It costs ${amount * prices[name]}`);
 }
```

Hint: Don't use a form if you dont want to send something to the server (just use `<input>` only), it makes things complicated, and give appropriate names to variables and functions!